# Chrome Packaged Apps sharing local data whilst disconnected form internet

Tags: database, google-chrome, indexeddb, google-chrome-app

Im developing a 'Multi-User' app and considering using the new(ish) chrome packaged app platform but I have a local database question.

As I understand it (correct me if im wrong), I can store data locally with IndexedDB, but this is exclusively run on the users browser so is only relevant to that user, any changes can only sync when the user is on-line (needing an internet connection).

My app must adhere to the 'offline first' model but as each local user is located in the same physical office on a local network, id like these users to be able to share and sync the applications data without an internet connection (in case its gone down). Meaning we don't bring the whole office down if internet fails, a sort of 'off-line multi user' model.

Is there a way for a chrome packaged app to store data on an internal local database, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [sockets](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network.html) to interact with your local network, but if I had to do it, i would use a local web server as a fallback when the internet connection is offline.

Comment: Thanks. Yes local web server is what I was looking at but it looks like too much work for this job.

Answer (score 2):

That would be a pretty neat feature. Unfortunately, there aren't any web APIs (or Chrome Apps APIs) that specifically facilitate peer-to-peer communication. As xmarcos says, the primitives are there for you to build it yourself, but it would be a pretty big undertaking.

Also one correction to your question: IndexedDB doesn't sync unless you build a syncing infrastructure on top of it yourself. You might be thinking about [chrome.storage.sync](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html). However, even in that case, the syncing is replicating only a user's own data, not doing a collaborative merge of multiple users' data into a single repository. You seem to be wanting the latter, and for that you're on your own.

You might be interested in reading more about distributed version control. Here's [one concise description of a complicated topic](http://cbx33.github.io/gitt/afterhours4-1.html).

Comment: Thanks, Its really a shame that there is no off-line syncing infrastructure, this is basic schoolboy stuff in enterprise office app dev (ie company in-house DB). I cant use Chrome Packaged Apps in this situation without reinventing the wheel and I really wanted to. looks like WPF.

Comment: Actually, WebRTC is intending to solve the peer-to-peer communication problem. They introduced DataChannels to allow for generic data transfer over the protocol. That said, you'd still need to roll a lot of stuff yourself to keep a database in sync across devices. And even then, you'd probably need to have the web app running on both machines at the same time to sync up the data.

Comment: emil, I'm glad to hear you say that. I'd read the WebRTC spec recently for precisely this reason and convinced myself that using it for pure P2P communication would be a hack (which would be sad because it solves so many practical issues such as NAT traversal). I'll give it another look, steeled by your encouraging opinion.